# Calculation of 2D bounds out of 3D vector

Tags: 3d, position, 2d

I am currently creating myself a set of  java classes for working with basic 3D shapes, and currently need help with displaying a cuboid on a 2D drawing surface(i.e canvas).

I know that this question is probably mostly mathematical, but how do you get the bounds/2D-vector of a corner point if you have the objects 3 rotation angles around each axis and the 3D vector of the point's pos in relation to the center of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself now. To apply the rotations, I use "rotation matrixes", which can change the values of a coordinate like in a rotation. For this I created a class containing some of the Mathematics of matrixes. Then I multiplied the original coordinates with each existing rotation matrix of the 3rd dimension. After that I used the formula (X|Y|Z) => (X/Z|Y/Z) to get the 2D bounds.